# Php, session.save_path

Tags: php, session

I wanted to ask about **session.save_path** from **php.ini** file (http://php.net/session.save-path), My question is where is the session is saved if I am not setting any path(`;session.save_path =`), **Is it on my PC memory?**, **Is it on files that located outside php directory?**,So far i see that with  **session.save_path set**, I can view the files, And when session.save_path is unset(`http://php.net/session.save-path`), I don't know where the files if there is any, If anyone can help me i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) is your friend here, in the output you'll find the original (left column) and overridden (right column) `session.save_path`.

Comment: I understand what your are saying but my question is where the session is saved if no session.save_path is not set, All i can see in phpinfo() is that there is value or there isn't value.

Answer (score 0):

Default is usually `/tmp` on linux based servers

`session.save_path` is set to nothing in `phpinfo()` if the default setting is being used

Answer (score 0):

If the option is commented out in your php.ini (as it is in mine), then php will use a default value. I show two quick options to get that value from the command line:

1. Non interactive:

```
$ php -i | grep session.save_path
session.save_path => /var/lib/php/sessions => /var/lib/php/sessions
```

2. Interactive:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled
     
php > echo session_save_path();
/var/lib/php/sessions

php > exit
```